# Possible to get exit URL in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a site set up with Google Analytics (GA). I'm looking to find out what URL visitors are going to most frequently when leaving the site.

I know how to get the exit URL in the site itself that is the last place they are, but is the external URL they are going to tracked in GA? Does the browser even tell the page being moved away from what the next URL it is going to? If not, I assume Google determines exit pages from not seeing any more hits from that particular user.

Thanks,
j

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to [tag external links individually](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55527), like so:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onClick="javascript: pageTracker._trackPageview('/outgoing/example.com');">
```

All clicks on that link would be tracked as if they were going to a page on your site called "/outgoing/example.com".

This only works for tracking clicks on external links. Security measures built into JavaScript and browsers mean you'll never be able to determine where users go if they manually type a new URL into the address bar, or use a bookmark.